# Conda MacOS Big Sur ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file

Tags: c++, conda, ld, macos-big-sur

When compiling a c++ project in a conda environment on MacOS Big Sur, the error
`ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file` may occur. How to proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Big Sur, the SDK that comes with Command Line Tools is too new. An older one needs to be downloaded and used:

1. Download the 10.10 SDK "MacOSX10.10.sdk.tar.xz" from [here](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases).
2. Extract it: `tar xf MacOSX10.10.sdk.tar.xz -C /opt`
3. Add following lines to `~/.condarc`:

```
conda_build:
  config_file: ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
```

4. create `~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml` if it doesn't exist and add:

```
CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT:
  - /opt/MacOSX10.10.sdk        # [osx]
```

Many thanks to `ihnorton` on this [thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9096).

Comment: I was a bit skeptical about this, particularly because it is such an old version of the SDK. However, looking into how Conda Forge builds their `osx-64` packages, I found [they are currently downloading SDK 10.9](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-ci-setup-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/download_osx_sdk.sh). So, yes this appears to just be how things are.

Comment: I used 10.10 because this [thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9096) says that is what the anaconda team is targeting (in 2018), but there are also suggestions there that newer SDK versions work too, e.g. up to 10.13

Comment: @rmwenzel no, you're right -  it's flexible infrastructure; however, Conda Forge still targets 10.9 in its package recipes. e.g., [Conda Forge pinning settings](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/blob/7bdadae1184906d8fb8b0d2943b2cd1579267a77/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml#L109).

Comment: Woops, I deleted my comment, for the record, I was saying that the conda recipe @merv linked to used whatever SDK was installed but defaulted to 10.9. And yeah, looks like Conda Forge targets 10.9, while [Anaconda targets 10.10](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html#macos-sdk) as OP mentioned.

Comment: Also FWIW I got the same error as OP trying to install packages in RStudio. In case anyone else has the same issue, you may need to update `.Rprofile` with `Sys.setenv(CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT = "/opt/MacOSX10.10.sdk")`, as a [comment](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9096#issuecomment-705130399) at the [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9096) referenced in this answer indicates.

Comment: Or just `export CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT="/opt/MacOSX10.10.sdk"` in your terminal config file, e.g.`.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`

Comment: Hi, I tried to export new link and create `~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml`. But both do not work. Old link to SKD still appear. `ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd' for architecture x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't want to build against conda (but just happen to be in a conda environment), you may be unwittingly using a conda-distributed `ld` that's incompatible with the newer system tools and libraries.

If your $PATH is set up so that Anaconda's `ld` has higher preference over the system linker, this will explain it:

```
$ which -a ld
/blah/anaconda3/bin/ld
/usr/bin/ld
```

If that's the case, reorder your PATH to put anaconda's directory after `/usr/bin`. Then, `which ld` should point to the system `ld`, and you should be good to go.