# Compiling fortran fails in a conda environment on MacOS Ventura with Xcode 14

Tags: xcode, anaconda, ld, macos-ventura

After I started using MacOS Ventura with Xcode 14, compiling a Fortran code in a conda environment failed. The error seems to be due to ld:

> ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file
> '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd'
> for architecture x86_64

The ld in Anaconda3/bin/ supports only Apple TAPI version 10.0.0

> @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-530 BUILD 07:42:29 Sep  7 2022 configured
> to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64
> x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
> LTO support using: LLVM version 14.0.6 (static support for 26, runtime is 29)
> TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 10.0.0 (tapi-1000.10.8)

Outside Anaconda, compiling works and the ld in /usr/bin/ supports Apple TAPI version 14.0.0

> @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-819.6 BUILD 21:47:27 Sep 13 2022
> configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32
> i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em LTO support using:
> LLVM version 14.0.0, (clang-1400.0.29.102) (static support for 29,
> runtime is 29) TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 14.0.0
> (tapi-1400.0.11)

To fix the problem, first, I tried both Xcode 14.01 and 14.1 (13.4 was incompatible with Ventura), but they didn't work.

Second, I tried using old SDK following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236331/conda-macos-big-sur-ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-tbd-in-yaml-file), but this also didn't work.

Since I want to stay in a conda environment managing python tools combined with Fortran,
any way to resolve the issue is very much appreciated!

Comment: This needs to be [reported to Anaconda](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues) if using only `defaults` (`anaconda`, `main`) channels. If you are using Conda Forge packages, create a minimal reproducible example (new environment outside of **base**, use only `conda-forge`) and report this to [the Conda Forge `compilers` feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/compilers-feedstock/issues).

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm using only the defaults channel, I will report it to Anaconda.

Comment: Just an update (already reported in the Anaconda community): I found that any created environment (i.e., except the base environment) ld supports TAPI version 14.0.0. on my macOS and I can compile my fortran code.