# Can't compile fortran on MacOS Monterey: ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file

Tags: gcc, ld, gfortran, macos-monterey, xcode-command-line-tools

I am facing an error whenever I try to compile fortran code:

```
% gfortran Testing_Fortran.f90 -o Testing_Fortran

ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Looking at similar issues through the internet, the most common solutions I've found are to downgrade the XCode command line tools, and to reinstall gcc, but none of this worked.

I tried CLTools 14.1 and 13.4, and I am installing gcc via homebrew. The gfortran version is 12.2.0. I'm on MacOS Monterey 12.6.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda MacOS Big Sur ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236331/conda-macos-big-sur-ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-tbd-in-yaml-file)

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue. I just deactivated Anaconda and run the fortran code.

```
conda deactivate
gfortran Testing_Fortran.f90 -o Testing_Fortranc
```

Again you can go back to Anaconda environment as,

```
conda activate
```

Answer (score 8):

It's likely that your `ld` isn't the latest system linker: both [on this help ticket](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55836#issuecomment-1295200406) and with a coworker the problem was that `ld` pointed to one from Anaconda. If your $PATH is set up so that Anaconda's `ld` has higher preference over the system linker, this will explain it:

```
$ which -a ld
/blah/anaconda3/bin/ld
/usr/bin/ld
```

If that's the case, reorder your PATH to put anaconda's directory after `/usr/bin`. Then, `which ld` should point to the system `ld`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: could you please mention how to edit the ld $PATH?

Comment: PATH is an environment variable. `echo $PATH` to print it, then reorder it and do `export PATH=/whatever:/your:/new:/path:/is`

Comment: `which -a ld` only showed `/usr/bin/ld` for me, but `conda deactivate` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75736450/377022 solved the issue anyway