# How do I get gfortran to work on Macbook pro with M2?

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran, macos-ventura

I am attempting to run gfortran on a 2022 Macbook pro with M2 and running Ventura 13.1 but I keep getting this error :

> ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file
> '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd'
> for architecture arm64

Any help with this? or is there another compiler out there compatible with apple m2 + ventura 13.1?

Not sure what to try in this case, I tried other solutions for M1 macs running gfortran but no success.

Comment: How did you install gfortran? Did you install the version that is intended for your CPU architecture? Try homebrew or similar.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I used a standalone installer  'gfortran-ARM-12.2-Ventura.dmg' and I also tried homebrew, but I get the same error either way. I did use the apple silicon 'arm' version when installing which is the version needed for my computer.

Comment: While one would think that such a thing - installing a compiler should be simple, and in most operating systems it indeed is, we have a notoriously high number of people with problems on MacOS. I mean, 90% or more people with such problems come here from MacOS. Hence I strongly recommend packaging distributions like Homebrew and always the latest packages update after any system update.

Comment: If you did try homebrew and have similar problems, you will need to provide the exact details. The exact commands you run and the exact error output you received. You may need to also update the command line tools that probably come with Xcode. Please note that I have never used MacOS. Only the exceptionally (really!) high number of askers coming with problems from MacOS made me to remember some key points.

Comment: I have the same problem trying to compile the most stupid hello world using brew g++-12 and the linker error is the only thing I get

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I used `brew install gcc` and also ensured xcode command line tools were up to date. When I run `gfortran -o hello ptest.f90` I get the following error:  `ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.      The script I test with:  program hello  

  print *, 'Hello, World!'
end program hello

Comment: Blame Apple....

Comment: Yup. I am currently remote into an linux machine to get the work I need done. I will update this thread if I find a solution however.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74318052/cant-compile-fortran-on-macos-monterey-ld-unsupported-tapi-file-type-tapi-t) worked for me. Essentially, I deactivated conda and then added the linker flag `-ld_classic` to compile the Fortran code. Also, I stuck with gcc installed from Homebrew and am on Xcode 15 and Ventura 13.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the dmg gfortran from [github gfortran for macOS](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases)